# Local notification with 'banner' in unity android

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, localnotification, prime31

I am using [Etcetra Plugin](https://prime31.com/docs#androidEtc) for scheduling local notifications and its working fine. I'm wondering if I can specify banner with notification so it looks like this : 
[image]

I have tried it with Remote Push notifications and it worked but I'm unable to see any function or parameter to specify banner with prime31 plugin. Any idea?

Here is the structure of Prime31 local notification

```
  public int scheduleNotification(long secondsFromNow, String title, String subtitle, String tickerText, String data, int requestCode)
  {
    Activity context = getActivity();
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, AlarmManagerReceiver.class);
    intent.putExtra("title", title);
    intent.putExtra("subtitle", subtitle);
    intent.putExtra("tickerText", tickerText);
    intent.putExtra("data", data);
    intent.putExtra("contextClassName", getActivity().getClass().getName());
    intent.putExtra("requestCode", requestCode);

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, requestCode, intent, 134217728);

    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService("alarm");
    alarmManager.set(1, System.currentTimeMillis() + secondsFromNow * 1000L, pendingIntent);

    return requestCode;
  }
```

Any idea how to assign banner here? please excuse me as I have no idea about Android native code.

Comment: Check out [Notification.BigPictureStyle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.BigPictureStyle.html) style from android documentation.But how is your plugin's structure, if it's a jar file you can copy the source code and add this to make a new jar maybe?

Comment: Have you found a solution?

Comment: Yes, for local notification we can't do I guess but for push notification there is a field called banner, just assign image path (uploaded some where on servers) and it will do the rest. I am using PushWoosh at the moment and its working fine